# Mongorestore not work (Invalid BSON size error)

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore

I run following command to get a dump from MongoDB collection:

```
docker exec -it mongo mongodump --db db_name --collection col_name --out - | gzip > output.gz
```

and I run following command to restore into other Mongo database:

```
mongorestore --host=localhost --port=27200 --db=db_name2 /path/output.bson
```

however I got following error:

```
Failed: db_name2.col_name: error restoring from path/output.bson.bson: reading bson input: invalid BSONSize: 808595506 bytes
```

is there any idea?
thanks

Comment: Write dump output to file via command line argument instead of redirecting stdout, ensure the file is not corrupt.

Comment: Then restore using the same version of tools that dumped.

Comment: Could you provide an example @D.SM?

Answer (score 1):

Try to look at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66581011/8808983

In general, it means that one of the documents you are trying to restore is too big.
You need to delete this doc and then try to restore it.