# Mongodb can dump but not to store "error restoring from <db-name.bson> an insert is too big"

Tags: mongodb, size, store, document, dump

I faced a problem in one of my customers db, there was a document that inflates to 16 MB size, which reached the limit of mongodb "max document size": https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/

To debug it I dumped the db with the `mongodump` command, which created BSON files for my db.
I tried to reload the dumped db to mongo on my machine with the command `mongorestore`, but I god the error:

```
Failed: Data.events: error restoring from /dbimport/Data/events.bson: an inserted document is too large
```

How can it be that I can't reload a dumped db?
I thought it may be because the size of the document is very close to the "max limit size" (16MB), but not exceeded it, so it's in my db, but when trying to import this document with the `mongostore` command it's too close to the "max limit size", so mongo refuses to insert it to the db.

Is there is an option to make the mongostore command to success in this scenario?

Comment: Find the offending documents and check their size. If size exceeds 16mb you won't be able to insert them. Otherwise update your tooling.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to manually open the BSON files (with python), find the big documents and remove some part of it, then write the BSON object to a new BSON file and load the edited BSON file, which was successfully stored to mongo.

This not fulfill my wish to be able to load the dumped db to the system without change it!

Python3:

```
import bson
from pprint import pprint

def get_bson_data(filename):
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        data = bson.decode_all(f.read())

    return data


def report_problematics_documents(data):
    problematics = []

    for item in data:
        if is_too_big(item):
            print(item)input("give me some more...")
            input("give me some more...")
            problematics.append(item)

    print(f"data len: {len(data)}")
    print(f"problematics: {problematics}")
    print(f"problematics len: {len(problematics)}")
        

def shrink_data(data):
    for i,  item in enumerate(data):
        if is_too_big(item):
            data[i] = shrink_item(item) # or delete it...
            print(f"item shrinked: {i}")


def write_bson_file(data, filename):
    new_filename = filename
    with open(new_filename, "wb") as f:
        for event in data:
            bson_data = bson.BSON.encode(event)
            f.write(bson_data)

def is_too_big(item):
    # you need to implement this one...
    pass


def shrink_item(item):
    # you need to implement this one...
    pass


def main():
    bson_file_name = "/path/to/file.bson"
    data = get_bson_data(bson_file_name)
    report_problematics_documents(data)

    shrink_data(data)
    report_problematics_documents(data)

    new_filename = bson_file_name + ".new"
    write_bson_file(data, new_filename)
    
    print("Load new data")
    data = get_bson_data(new_filename)
    report_problematics_documents(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```